# How to make an image overlay the bottom shadow of the containing element

Tags: html, css

I want the legs of the girl to appear on the "border" or box-shadow. I want the image 5px down.

Here's the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9rwuz4Lq/2/

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

main {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
}

main h2 {}

main img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  main img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SwZDvlS.png">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <P>BLABLA</P>
  <P>BLABLA</P>


</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get away with just `position: relative` the image and giving it your `-5px` offset. Check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/L6kgfcyh/8/).

Full disclosure: I did tweak your layout a bit so you don't have to deal with floats, but the basic concept still applies.

```
main img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the image to be position absolute in the main div and the position of the main tag to be position relative.

Then you have to set the top and left Pixels .

Comment: This will cause the box to collapse in height. Your answer should include actual markup and CSS.